# Update Json from URL

Tags: java, json, rest, firebase, updates

Im using Firebase to get Json from a uri that is

https://resplendent-inferno-1315.firebaseio.com/Sensor.json

When i get data works fine and if i delete is ok ..... im trying to find a way to

update data for example if i have in my url this json

```
{"Brand":"fat-re32","Temp":16}
```

and i wont to update Temp in 25 how can i do that ?

I have tried http put method but that produse json i url like these

```
{"-DELF648645fss68f5-56" :{"Temp":125} , "Brand":"fat-re32","Temp":16}
```

Can anyone give a sugestion im using java so plz show a ex in Java or a library :)

Comment: Here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/save-data#section-update

Using Java you need to go to the ref "-DELF648645fss68f5-56" and use the put method to update.

Comment: What is library used in this case ?

Comment: You asked for Java, so I gave you reference for Java